# Floats in lists halt the parser with 'no available options' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, peg, grako

Given [this grammar](http://paste.aerdan.org/6i0Y):

```
(* integers *)
DEC = /([1-9][0-9]*|0+)/;
int = /(0b[01]+|0o[0-7]+|0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)/ | DEC;

(* floats *)
pointfloat = /([0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.)/;
expfloat = /([0-9]+\.?|[0-9]*\.)[eE][+-]?[0-9]+/;
float = pointfloat | expfloat;

list = '[' @+:atom {',' @+:atom}* ']';

(* atoms *)
identifier = /[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*/;
symbol = int        |
         float      |
         identifier |
         list;

(* functions *)
arglist = @+:atom {',' @+:atom}*;
function = identifier '(' [arglist] ')';
atom = function | symbol;

prec8 = '(' atom ')' | atom;
prec7 = [('+' | '-' | '~')] prec8;
prec6 = prec7 ['!'];
prec5 = [prec6 '**'] prec6;
prec4 = [prec5 ('*' | '/' | '%' | 'd')] prec5;
prec3 = [prec4 ('+' | '-')] prec4;
(* <| and >| are rotate-left and rotate-right, respectively. They assume the nearest C size. *)
prec2 = [prec3 ('<<' | '>>' | '<|' | '>|')] prec3;
prec1 = [prec2 ('&' | '|' | '^')] prec2;

expr = prec1 $;
```

and [this semantics object](http://paste.aerdan.org/0nAH):

```
class ChessaSemantics:
    def int(self, ast):
        return int(ast)

    def float(self, ast):
        return float(ast)

    def list(self, ast):
        return ast

    def identifier(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, str) and ast in variables:
            return variables[ast]
        else:
            return ast

    def function(self, ast):
        func = funcs[ast[0]][0]
        args = ast[2:-1]
        if len(args) < funcs[ast[0]][1]:
            raise ValueError('insufficient arguments')
        return func(*args)

    def prec8(self, ast):
        return ast

    def prec7(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, list) and len(ast) > 1 and not isinstance(ast[0], (int, float, list)):
            return unop[ast[0]](ast[1])
        else:
            return ast

    def prec6(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, list) and len(ast) > 1 and not isinstance(ast[1], (int, float, list)):
            return unop[ast[1]](ast[0])
        else:
            return ast

    def prec5(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, list) and len(ast) > 2 and not isinstance(ast[1], (int, float, list)):
            return binop[ast[1]](ast[0], ast[2])
        else:
            return ast

    def prec4(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, list) and len(ast) > 2 and not isinstance(ast[1], (int, float, list)):
            return binop[ast[1]](ast[0], ast[2])
        else:
            return ast

    def prec3(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, list) and len(ast) > 2 and not isinstance(ast[1], (int, float, list)):
            return binop[ast[1]](ast[0], ast[2])
        else:
            return ast

    def prec2(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, list) and len(ast) > 2 and not isinstance(ast[1], (int, float, list)):
            return binop[ast[1]](ast[0], ast[2])
        else:
            return ast

    def prec1(self, ast):
        if isinstance(ast, list) and len(ast) > 2 and not isinstance(ast[1], (int, float, list)):
            return binop[ast[1]](ast[0], ast[2])
        else:
            return ast
```

...my parser halts with `no available options` errors when encountering a list with non-integral elements (floats or lists; variables are fine, though).

Examples:

- `drop(4d6, 1)`
- `[1.5, 2, 3]`

Interestingly enough, `drop([1, 2, 4, 2], 1)` behaves correctly and outputs `[2, 4, 2]`.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question so that people will still be able to read it next month. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? There's an awful lot of Python in the second paste, and SO got grouchy at me when I tried to inline it.

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was a size limit (I'm still very new here) but I do agree that your linked material is rather large. It would be _much_ better if you could post an abridged version of the program that exhibits the error. Try to isolate the problem into a chunk of code that others can both read and run. If that's too hard to do, you could simplify your grammar so that it only handles a single operator. Or something. The smaller your program is the more likely it is that people will read it. If you post no code on StackOverflow, you're unlikely to get much help.

Comment: Following the StackOveflow suggestions and norms is the best way to get quick and good answers. Also keep in mind that there's a tacit norm that you should try to do your homework at your best before asking for help.

Comment: Oh, definitely. My concern was mostly that I didn't want to provide too little information to be useful.

Comment: How are we supposed to debug that? We can't run it, and it refers to various mysterious data structures and functions.

Comment: @PM2Ring: it is not mysterious if you are familiar with Grako. The only thing that is missing is `parse()` call so we can assume the default. [Here's complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195510/4279).

Comment: Rightio, @J.F.Sebastian; I'm not familiar with Grako. But I'm glad that this question hasn't been lost in oblivion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rule precedence issue with grako](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016475/rule-precedence-issue-with-grako)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make a minimal example?

Comment: Wasn't this question answered in another forum? If so, please post your own answer here. At any rate, it seems that the regular expressions for floats are wrong.