# Processing repeatedly structured text file with python

Tags: python, parsing, text, parser-generator

I have a big text file structured in blocks like:

```
Student = {
        PInfo = {
                ID   = 0001;
            Name.First = "Joe";
            Name.Last = "Burger";
            DOB  = "01/01/2000";
        };
        School = "West High";
        Address = {
            Str1 = "001 Main St.";
            Zip = 12345;
        };
    };
    Student = {
        PInfo = {
            ID   = 0002;
            Name.First = "John";
            Name.Last = "Smith";
            DOB  = "02/02/2002";
        };
        School = "East High";
        Address = {
            Str1 = "001 40nd St.";
            Zip = 12346;
        };
        Club = "Football";
    };
    ....
```

The Student blocks share the same entries like "PInfo", "School" and "Address", but some of them may have additional entries, such as the "Club" information for "John Smith" which is not included for "Joe Burger". 
What I want to do is to get Name, School name and zip code of each student and store them in a dictionary, like

```
    {'Joe Burger':{School:'West High', Zip:12345}, 'John Smith':{School:'East High', Zip:12346}, ...}
```

Being new to python programming, I tried to open the file and analyze it line by line, but it looks so cumbersome. And the real file is quite large and more complicated than the example I posted above. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do it. Thanks ahead.

Comment: If its `json` or `yaml`, there are module which can read that data quite easily.

Comment: I asked a similar question yesterday but haven't received any answers yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173372/parsing-an-ad-hoc-tree . Upvoted your question

Comment: @spade: you got something completely different. And there is no magic algorithm which can autmagically comprehend a strucutre or pattern out of nothing. Gotta do it yourself; im sorry.

Comment: @DonQuestion, I see a great deal of similarity between the two problems unambiguously because both of them can be represented as n-ary trees. The patterns are very conspicuous to the human eye - it should be possible to train a machine to learn reading it. I was hoping for someone from compiler or even NLP areas to make suggestions on generic tree building from nested structures. In any case, I don't mean to hijack this thread and so will stop here.

Comment: you could try [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) or other [Python parsers](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html) to create a parser for your input format.

Answer (score 4):

To parse the file you could define a grammar that describes your input format and use it to generate a parser.

There are [many language parsers in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing). For example, you could use [Grako](https://bitbucket.org/apalala/grako/overview) that takes grammars in a variation of [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) as input, and outputs memoizing [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) parsers in Python.

To install Grako, run `pip install grako`.

Here's grammar for your format using Grako's flavor of EBNF syntax:

```
(* a file is zero or more records *)
file = { record }* $;
record = name '=' value ';' ;
name = /[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.]*/ ;
value = object | integer | string ;
(* an object contains one or more records *)
object = '{' { record }+ '}' ;
integer = /[0-9]+/ ;
string = '"' /[^"]*/ '"';
```

To generate parser, save the grammar to a file e.g., `Structured.ebnf` and run:

```
$ grako -o structured_parser.py Structured.ebnf
```

It creates `structured_parser` module that can be used to extract the student information from the input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from structured_parser import StructuredParser

class Semantics(object):
    def record(self, ast):
        # record = name '=' value ';' ;
        # value = object | integer | string ;
        return ast[0], ast[2] # name, value
    def object(self, ast):
        # object = '{' { record }+ '}' ;
        return dict(ast[1])
    def integer(self, ast):
        # integer = /[0-9]+/ ;
        return int(ast)
    def string(self, ast):
        # string = '"' /[^"]*/ '"';
        return ast[1]

with open('input.txt') as file:
    text = file.read()
parser = StructuredParser()
ast = parser.parse(text, rule_name='file', semantics=Semantics())
students = [value for name, value in ast if name == 'Student']
d = {'{0[Name.First]} {0[Name.Last]}'.format(s['PInfo']):
     dict(School=s['School'], Zip=s['Address']['Zip'])
     for s in students}
from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

#### Output

```
{'Joe Burger': {'School': u'West High', 'Zip': 12345},
 'John Smith': {'School': u'East High', 'Zip': 12346}}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not json, but similar structured. you should be able to reformat it into json.

1. "=" -> ":"
2. quote all keys with '"'
3. ";" -> ","
4. remove all "," which are followed by a "}"
5. put it in curly braces
6. parse it with json.loads

Answer (score 1):

For such thing, I use [Marpa::R2](https://metacpan.org/release/Marpa-R2), a [Perl](http://www.perl.org/) interface to [Marpa, a general BNF parser](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html). It allows decribing the text as a grammar rules and parse them to a tree of arrays (parse tree). You can then traverse the tree to save the results as a hash of hashes (hash is perl for python's dictionary) or use it as is.

I cooked a working example using your input: [parser](https://gist.github.com/rns/40a10da861f10d4f9912#file-parser-pl), 
[result tree](https://gist.github.com/rns/40a10da861f10d4f9912#file-parse-results).

Hope this helps.

P.S. Example of `ast_traverse()`: [Parse values from a block of text based on specific keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179905/parse-values-from-a-block-of-text-based-on-specific-keys/26182278#26182278)