# Reading .sol file to skim out relevant information

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, readline

I have a .sol file at my hand and I would like to read the relevant information out of it. The following lines are just a part of the .sol file. What the file represents is the variables `z,x,f`. The number that follows `z` is the request ID. Now, the numbers that follow `x` are explained as below. First number following _ is the request ID, second number is the virtual node number and the final number is the physical node on which it is embedded. Similarly incase of `f`, the first number is the requestID, second is the edgeID, the numbers in the first () represent the virtual edge and the numbers in the second () represent the physical edge. I want to write a function to take these values and create an .xml file which would enable better reading of the required information and can be re-used efficiently. But the problem I'm having is I'm unable to read them and sort them out accordingly. Hence, I thought of asking you guys for help.

Thank You

```
z_0                  1.000000
x_0_0_1              1.000000
x_0_1_5              1.000000
x_0_2_20             1.000000
x_0_3_21             1.000000
x_0_4_8              1.000000
f_0_0(0,1)_(1,5)     1.000000
f_0_1(1,2)_(5,9)     1.000000
f_0_1(1,2)_(9,20)    1.000000
f_0_2(2,3)_(2,21)    1.000000
f_0_2(3,2)_(2,22)    1.000000
f_0_2(2,3)_(20,22)   1.000000
f_0_3(4,3)_(8,10)    1.000000
f_0_3(3,4)_(0,10)    1.000000
f_0_3(4,3)_(0,14)    1.000000
f_0_3(4,3)_(14,21)   1.000000
z_1                  1.000000
x_1_0_16             1.000000
x_1_1_6              1.000000
x_1_2_13             1.000000
x_1_3_0              1.000000
x_1_4_25             1.000000
x_1_5_15             1.000000
x_1_6_19             1.000000
f_1_0(1,0)_(6,16)    1.000000
f_1_1(0,2)_(6,11)    1.000000
f_1_1(0,2)_(11,13)   1.000000
f_1_1(2,0)_(6,16)    1.000000
f_1_2(3,1)_(0,6)     1.000000
f_1_3(2,4)_(13,25)   1.000000
f_1_4(5,4)_(15,25)   1.000000
f_1_5(3,6)_(0,1)     1.000000
f_1_5(3,6)_(1,18)    1.000000
f_1_5(3,6)_(18,19)   1.000000
```

Comment: you could use regular expressions or even a full custom parser: feed ebnf to `grako` (or other parser-generator) and build json, xml on the semantics step, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26184812/4279).

Comment: Thanks for the idea Sebastian. I used the split command repeatedly to get the values and it seems like its working but its bad in a way because it reminds me of low programming skills.I shall check out the grako package